# if finding element with phpsimpledom failed

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using **simplephpdom** For finding the title of one speciall page like this :

```
function get_title_with_dom($url) {
$amounts = array();
$html = file_get_html($url);
$elements = $html->find('title');
return trim($elements[0]->innertext);
}
```

So, now there is a problem for the pages that does NOT have title !

I will get this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in ...

So, HOW can i say, if could not find element , then return **NULL** or **FALSE** ?

I tried to use such this blow function , but it doesn't work (work like code above) :

```
function get_title_with_dom($url) {
$amounts = array();
$html = file_get_html($url);
if (!($html->find('title'))) {
  return false;
} else {
  $elements = $html->find('title');
  return trim($elements[0]->innertext);
}
}
```

Comment: why do you have both `str_get_html` and `file_get_html` in the function? just use `file_get_html`

Comment: @Ghost I think the first one is not useful , i will delete it, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both `str_get_html` and `file_get_html`. If you're feeding the url just use `file_get_html`.

```
function get_title_with_dom($url) {
    $data = false;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $title = $html->find('title', 0);
    if($title) {
        $data = $title->innertext;
    }
    return $data;
}

var_dump(get_title_with_dom('http://www.google.com')); // Google
var_dump(get_title_with_dom('http://codepad.viper-7.com/moj97E')); // bool(false)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but the error comes again ! in this line : `$title = $html->find('title', 0);`

Comment: @Pap you sure bro? i tested it with a page with and without a title tag it works fine. can i have an example url to test with?